Body of the largest area which can get into a $3\times 3$ room through a length $1$ door
I created this problem as a (supposedly) much simpler analogue of a notoriously difficult Moving sofa problem. The latter is still unsolved. Yet, the rigorous solution of the following problem is still to be found.
Problem.

Prove or disprove that a largest plane body which can get into a square $3\times 3$ room through a length $1$ door (made exactly in the middle of one of the sides) has an area equal to $3+\frac{\pi}{4}=3.7853_{+}$.

If the above can be disproved, find the largest possible area.


(Such a clumsy formulation is only in order to present a constructive part of the problem separately).
The example where the given bound is achieved is shown here:


How about a zig-zag figure made by alternating narrow rhombuses with side length 1 and small vertex angle $\alpha$, and circular segments of angle $\alpha$. With a small $\alpha$ this is almost a 2x3 rectangle with triangular notches along the sides, but it has to be tapered slightly to avoid hitting the top/bottom of the room as you tilt it up/down by angle $\alpha$ to get through the door. Those notches cut away about $1/4$ of the area. In the limit you get an area of $6*3/4=9/2$ so it should be possible to use this to beat your solution.

I will intently try to understand Your construction. If it works, will add a picture.

I hope my description is clear. When I have time to work it out more I'll draw something and write it up as an answer.

https://imgur.com/a/ZDWtPHL @JaapScherphuis means this I think (subject to tapering the top-left and bottom-left)

@BenjaminWang Yes that shows the main idea, though to beat the OP's solution I suspect there will need to be a few more zig-zags.

We need to think thoroughly whether this construction really works:
https://imgur.com/BbPjQrB

Is there a reason you expect this problem to be "much simpler" to rigorously prove? It's not at all obvious to me at first glance, and it seems plausible that it's in fact harder.

Yes, though the reason is rather intuitive. We can think of this problem not as one asking to force a body through a door, but one where a door continuously slides through the body. It is natural to suppose that (apart from some initial and final  stages) the whole segment of length $1$ belongs to the body. This does not mean that a body can be described as a $\frac{1}{2}$ neighborhood of a certain curve. Truly, if we were to consider a corridor of width $1$ and a door of length $1$, the area of the body which can be forced into a corridor is unlimited, though at one end it become very narrow.

(ctnd.) The center of the corridor draws a curve in 3D space; here third coordinate corresponds to an angle of orientation. The geometry of the room itself only manifests as a set of constrains telling which finite curves are allowed. Now, consider a moving sofa problem. Let us joint two corners by a segment of length $\sqrt{2}$ (a barrier). A barrier also slides through the body (this movement can also be assigned a 3D curve), but a length of its intersection with a body varies. This is one of the reasons which lets me suppose that the presented problem is (most likely) easier.

(Correction: a center of a door). Another reason to assume that the presented problem is easier is the following: we can change the shape of the room, pass to dimension $D>2$, change the shape of the door (which is of dimension $D-1$), and so on. A full solution to any of these problems would shed some light on the initial problem. On the other hand, the moving sofa case is mainly tight to a dimension $2$. Truly, this makes it more fundamental, not depending on one's choice. And at the same time (supposedly) more difficult to solve. But these are only speculations, of course :)
